# How to create a NSDictionary with blank key/ without key for an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to create a JSON string from a `NSDictionary`.The complete JSON to create is given below.

```
{
     "source":"point a ",
     "destination":"point b ",
     "boardingPoint":{
           "id":"2222",
           "location":"Some location"
},
"customerName":"test",
"customerLastName":"testing",
"customerEmail":"test@gmail.com",
"blockSeatPaxDetails":[
  {
     "age":"20",
     "name":"test123",
     "sex":"M",
     "title":"Mr",
     "email":"testing@gmail.com"
  }
],
"inventory":0
}
```

Now I am stuck at creating dictionary for the first part of this JSON ie

```
    {
    "source": "point a ",
    "destination": "point b ",
    "boardingPoint": {
    "id": "2222",
    "location": "Some location",

   },
```

Here the boardingPoint is a dictionary which is added to one dictionary.And then along with rest of the keys I make a final dictionary.So when I create the final dictionary, with `objectsAndKeys` I have no key to set for the first part which is shown below.If I set blank like this `@" "` the JSON string shows `" "` as key.And ofcourse I cannot use `nil`.How to do it then?

This is how it apppears if I insert blank as key for the first part

```
  {
  "" : {

    "source" : "point a",
    "boardingPoint" : {
    "id" : "2222",
    "location" : "Some location",
  },
    "destination" : "point b"
 },
```

This is how I create the  dictionaries

```
  NSDictionary *boardingPoint = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:boardingPointID,@"id", boardingLocation,@"location",nil];

  NSDictionary *firstDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:source,@"source",dest,@"destination",nil];

 NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstDictionary, @" ",customerName,@"customerName",customerLastName,@"customerLastName",customerEmail,@"customerEmail",blockSeatPaxDetails,@"blockSeatPaxDetails",inventory,@"inventory",nil];
```

and then ofcourse

```
     NSData *finalData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mainDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
```

Comment: You totally garbled the indentation.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that.Edited it to the best so far .

Comment: [NSNull Null] for nil in NSDictionaries or NSArrays

Comment: Where do you get the second `{` ahead of "source"??  It's not there in your first listing.

Comment: And don't use `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` -- it's too verbose and confusing.  Either create an NSMutableDictionary and do `setObject:forKey:` for each item individually, or use the `@{key1:object1,key2:object2}` notation.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'             -------gives this if [NSNull null] is used

Comment: And there is no reason to use NSNull unless you want `null` for a value somewhere in your JSON.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your JSON, properly indented, is:

```
{

    "source":"point a ",
    "destination":"point b ",
    "boardingPoint":{
        "id":"2222",
        "location":"Some location",
    },
    "customerName":"test",
    "customerLastName":"testing",
    "customerEmail":"test@gmail.com",
    "blockSeatPaxDetails":[
        {
            "age":"20",
            "name":"test123",
            "sex":"M",
            "title":"Mr",
            "email":"testing@gmail.com",
        },
```

(You've apparently elided something toward the end so I can't slow the last few lines.)

There is no "missing key" or anything of the sort.  If you feed your (unelided) JSON through NSJSONSerialization it will produce the correct "tree" of dictionaries and arrays.